# What are the red flags for scammy ICOs?

Tags: tokens, ico

I'm new to crypto currencies, trying to get my head around how to evaluate different projects. In general, what are red flags to look out for? Is there anywhere trustworthy that compiles or critical evaluations?

As case study, this one, [Appian](https://appian.io/), sets off alarm bells to me, I'd like to see if others are reading it the same way. It's a perfectly viable enough idea that can plausibly be a real project: an app store for dapps, along with developer tools.

However, I can't find anything written about it, only uncritical reprinting of their press release. There's no information about the people behind it or ways to contact them. There's no evidence in the whitepaper or elsewhere to back up the claims that they actually have the software or expertise they claim. In particular the app builder seems to me like a big project that they'd want to show off a lot more if they actually had it.

Another suspicious thing is that there's already a software company called Appian. Surely they would have done a quick google of the name if they were serious about the project, whereas a scammer might hope the confusion will lend them credibility?

Comment: Go see reddit for this one

Comment: This has 4 votes for being opinion-based but I think some reasonable answers can be posted.  I will try...  Maybe this question also needs to be edited to be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some red flags:

- Anonymous team
- Funds sent immediately to team (see [this](https://medium.com/@matthewdif/towards-responsible-token-sales-icos-291e69cc9ccf))
- ICO launch without sufficient time for community to examine
- Team without a track record
- Team without any code
- Team without any product or demo
- Team without a white paper
- Team with little history in the community
- Team that tries to cause confusion with an existing company or project
- Team that lies
- Team with inaccuracies about their background, resumes, etc...
- Team with technical claims that are objectively wrong
- Team without endorsements
- Team without reputable partners
- Team without reputably audited code
- Team without milestones

Note that the opposite of the above does not mean that an ICO is legitimate.

Comment: Nice list! Something to add: team that can't be reached using their usual contact methods; I can't remember which ICO it was, but I recall there being some scammers who pretended to be some respected individuals in the crypto space.